# ssh hangs if remote machine is switched off

Tags: ssh, scripts

I want to log the status of a particular interface in my remote machine periodically. The following code does the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "1" ]
do
    ifconfig usb0 &>/dev/null
    if [ "$(echo $?)" == "0" ]
    then
        sshpass -p passwd ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 duser@10.1.1.3 ifconfig wave-data
    else
        echo "usb0 disconnected"
    fi
    sleep 0.2
done
```

The remote machine is connected via the usb0 interface. I want this code to be robust. So i am testing it by frequently powering off and powering on my remote machine. The problem is sometimes when i power off the machine, the code stuck and it is not printing anything. I suppose if ssh is interrupted in the middle of executing it is getting stuck. How can i overcome this? Is there any alternate way to execute command on a remote machine and get the output? thank you.

Comment: I think the `trap` utility might be useful for you. Read how to use it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15785522/1505348).